# I want to set repeating alarm that triggers every day at different time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeat

I need the alarm to be triggered every day at sunrise.
I get the sunrise time like this:"06:55"

```
Location location = new Location(latitude, longitude);
SunriseSunsetCalculator calculator = new SunriseSunsetCalculator(location, "GMT"+localTime);
String officialSunrise = calculator.getOfficialSunriseForDate(Calendar.getInstance());
```

That means every day the time to trigger will be different.

```
alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startmillis,intervalmillis, wakeUp);
```

I would appreciate general guidance on what direction to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting an alarm that will go off at a different time each day. You should set separate alarms each day. I recommend you do this by setting the next days alarm after an alarm goes off.

Comment: Thanks, I need the user to set his/her preferences once and the alarm to work until cancelled by the user from preferences

Comment: @BestSiteEditor Based off of my solution this is still possible. Even if you could set all the alarms at once, this would be as you have to decide how many alarms to set... Please accept the answer if I've helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

[Android Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/) has [recently announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/semantic-time-support-now-available-on.html) new features that provide a simple solution for your use-case (that avoids you having to explicitly manage location request and computing sunrise times). The way to achieve what you're trying to do is to create and register a TimeFence specified relative to sunrise/sunset.

For example:

```
// Create TimeFence
AwarenessFence sunriseFence =
    TimeFence.aroundTimeInstant(TimeFence.TIME_INSTANT_SUNRISE,
        0, 5 * ONE_MINUTE_MILLIS);

// Register fence with Awareness.
Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
    mGoogleApiClient,
    new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
        .addFence("fenceKey", sunriseFence, myPendingIntent)
        .build())
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Fence was successfully registered.");
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Fence could not be registered: " + status);
            }
        }
    });
```

You will get callbacks when the fence evaluates to TRUE at sunrise, and when it evaluates back to FALSE at 5-min after sunrise based on the settings above.

Please check [Fence API code snippets](https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/fence-api-overview) docs for how to add your custom app logic.